# Getting around long formula string

Tags: vba, excel

I had a macro that was working perfectly until I had to create a long formula to handle certain scenarios in the worksheet.  The formula basically creates a name from the text, that I than go ahead and rename the cell's tab with this name.  Here's the vba code:

```
Sub Tab_Name_Creation()
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim formula As String
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    s.Activate
    With ActiveWindow
        .View = xlNormalView
    End With

Next s
Call UnhideRows
formula = "= IF(R[-3]C=""Facility Variance Report"",IF(MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)=""Baptist Memorial Hos"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&"" ""&MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C)+1)+1,3)&""-FVar"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&MID(R[-2]C,FIN" & _
    "R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&""-FVar""),IF(MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)=""Baptist Memorial Hos"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&"" ""&MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C,FIND(""-" & _
    ")+1)+1,3)&""-LTM"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&""-LTM""))"

For i = 5 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).Range("A4").NumberFormat = "General"
    Worksheets(i).Range("A4") = formula
Next i

 Call RenameFromA4
 Call SortWorkBook
 Call listsheets
 MsgBox "Report Has Been Updated"
End Sub
```

Here's the formula:

```
=IF(A1="Facility Variance Report",IF(MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,20)="Baptist Memorial Hos",MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&TRIM((MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND("West",A2),0)>0," W","")&" "&MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1,3)&" -FVar",MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&TRIM((MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND("West",A2),0)>0," W","")&"-FVar"),IF(MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,20)="Baptist Memorial Hos",MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&TRIM((MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND("West",A2),0)>0," W","")&" "&MID(A2,FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2)+1)+1,3)&"-LTM",MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&TRIM((MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND("West",A2),0)>0," W","")&"-LTM"))
```

I need assistance is there a way I can concatenate the string?  Or do I have to find a way to condense the formula?

Comment: Why would you drop a formula onto a sheet within code when you can simply just code what you need and drop that result? XD Edit: did you copy that code or wrote it yourself? If latter, you know how to code!

Comment: I created the formula for the functionality of dissecting to create the tab name unique from each other.  Once I created the formula I simply record myself entering it so I can duplicate it across the whole workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep adding to the `formula` variable with `formula = formula + "text"`

```
Sub Tab_Name_Creation()
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim formula As String
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    s.Activate
    With ActiveWindow
        .View = xlNormalView
    End With

Next s
Call UnhideRows
formula = "=IF(R[-3]C=""Facility Variance Report"",IF(MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)=""Baptist Memorial Hos"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&"" ""&MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C)+1)+1,3)&""-FVar"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&MID(R[-2]C,FIN"
formula = formula + "R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&""-FVar""),IF(MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)=""Baptist Memorial Hos"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&"" ""&MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C,FIND(""-"
formula = formula + ")+1)+1,3)&""-LTM"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&""-LTM""))"

For i = 5 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).Range("A4").NumberFormat = "General"
    Worksheets(i).Range("A4") = formula
Next i

 Call RenameFromA4
 Call SortWorkBook
 Call listsheets
 MsgBox "Report Has Been Updated"
End Sub
```

Comment: to concantenate strings vba uses ampersand operator... i.e.  formula = formula & "text"