# Run time error '1004' for entering a formula into each sheet in the workbook

Tags: vba, excel

So I had a code that was working.  Basically pieces together different parts in cells A2 and A1 of each worksheet to create unique tab names.  But I ran into a situation of duplicate tab names.  So I adjusted the formula by making it a little longer to avoid these errors but now when I run the Macro I get Run-Time error '1004'.  With no clue on why because nothing changed but the formula.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Tab_Name_Creation()
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim formula As String
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

s.Activate
With ActiveWindow
    .View = xlNormalView
End With

Next s
Call UnhideRows
formula = "=IF(R[-3]C=""Facility Variance Report"",IF(MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)=""Baptist Memorial Hos"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&"" ""&MID(R[-2]C,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(R[-2]C,""-"",CHAR(1),2))+1,3)&"" -FVar"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM(" & _
    "2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&""-FVar""),IF(MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)=""Baptist Memorial Hos"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&"" ""&MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C)+1)+1,3)&""-LTM"",MID(" & _
    "ND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&""-LTM""))"

For i = 5 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).Range("A4").NumberFormat = "General"
    Worksheets(i).Range("A4") = formula
Next i


Call RenameFromA4
Call SortWorkBook
Call listsheets
MsgBox "Report Has Been Updated"
End Sub
```

To give you some background on the macro itself.  I have a sheet with about 94 sheets with the tab names in account numbers which made it hard for people to understand.  So i created this macro that first changes the workbook view to normal view, than unhide rows at the top of the spreadsheet, than inserts the formula that giving issue, than it renames the tabs, sort them and than create/organize a table of contents.

Any insight why I get run time error on line will be appreciated:

Worksheets(i).Range("A4") = formula

Example of the Formula 
Cell A1 contains :LTM Income Statement
Cell A2 Contains : HM_LA_217368 - HM: St. Martin Hospital

The formula in excel: `IF(A1="Facility Variance Report",IF(MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,20)="Baptist Memorial Hos",MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&TRIM((MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND("West",A2),0)>0," W","")&" "&MID(A2,FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2)+1)+1,3)&"-FVar",MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&TRIM((MID(2:2,FIND(":",A2)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND("West",A2),0)>0," W","")&"-FVar"),IF(MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,20)="Baptist Memorial Hos",MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&TRIM((MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND("West",A2),0)>0," W","")&" "&MID(A2,FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2)+1)+1,3)&"-LTM",MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&TRIM((MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND("West",A2),0)>0," W","")&"-LTM"))`

Produces a result of "LA-St. Martin Hospital-LTM" So that will be the new tab name.

So I concatenated the formula  to fit string :

```
formula = "=IF(R[-3]C=""Facility Variance Report"",IF(MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)=""Baptist Memorial Hos"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&"" ""&MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C)+1)+1,3)&""-FVar""" & _
formula = formula & "MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(2:2,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&""-FVar"")" & _
formula = formula & "IF(MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)=""Baptist Memorial Hos"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,17)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&"" ""&MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C,FIND(""-"",R[-2]C)+1)+1,3)&""-LTM""" & _
formula = forumla & "MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,20)))&IF(IFERROR(FIND(""West"",R[-2]C),0)>0,"" W"","""")&""-LTM""))"
```

Still getting a error on the string

Comment: Did you actually try this formula in Excel? Does it work? Try creating the formula in excel, start macro recorder, F2 on the cell, Enter, and use whatever the recorder created for you. Or go through it char-by-char, and find the missing comma. :)

Comment: 1) `formula` is a word that vba uses, change your variable to somthing else like `frmla`.  2) try `Worksheets(i).Range("A4").Formula = frmla`.  If that does not work double check you formula string to ensure it is correct.

Comment: Or even better, use `FormulaR1C1` `Worksheets(i).Range("A4").FormulaR1C1`

Comment: Show us the OLD formula, which worked, and show the NEW formula, which doesn't work. Please isolate the problem to the smallest piece of code possible.

Comment: I showed the formula in the edit, basically I recorded myself entering this formula than added it to the code.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie the prior code was the exact same only the formula changed

Comment: So, show us the OLD and NEW formula. The error must be there.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I think your right I see that when I recorded my formula excel chop off the end and begging parts

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner I realized that as I was combing thru the recording

Comment: Your formula string is invalid. The 255 characters limit is for array formulas, not R1C1 reference.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488575/getting-around-long-formula-string)? It seems abandoned.

Comment: @Jeeped  I took their suggestions on reformatting the string because macro recorder wasn't capturing all characters associated with the formula but I'm still getting a error.

Comment: So the answer wasn't correct...? The answer wasn't helpful...? This question seems more like it should have been little more than an addendum to teh first if the answer did not solve your problem. If it did and now you are just having trouble with the longer formula then this question could conceivably stand on its own but the last question should have been closed off with an accepted answer and possibly a helpful vote.